# cheerio each() function behaves strangely

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, deployment, cheerio

I have a code, which web-scraps the certain page. I use puppeteer+cheerio to do that. On my laptop code works perfectly. But after deploying it to the VDS, cheerio each() selector started working strangely. (But it still works fine on my laptop). The issue is that on VDS the following error occurs:

> (node:28544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
>       at Node. (/home/ubuntu/handbot/liveMonitoring.js:211:82)
>       at initialize.exports.each (/home/ubuntu/handbot/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/traversing.js:300:24)
>       at Node. (/home/ubuntu/handbot/liveMonitoring.js:182:29)
>       at initialize.exports.each (/home/ubuntu/handbot/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/traversing.js:300:24)
>       at liveMonitoring (/home/ubuntu/handbot/liveMonitoring.js:175:28)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   (node:28544) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:28544) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

The most interesting point is that sometimes the error disappears (There seems to be no pattern in which error occurs).
I was trying to fix this problem by reinstalling node js, but it did not work. The problem is not in my code (since it works on my laptop and even sometimes on vds). I think there is something with exporting of each() function. Since due to error message, there is something wrong happens in

> /home/ubuntu/handbot/node_modules/cheerio/lib/api/traversing.js:300:24

The code of the traversing.js (298-302 lines):

`

```
exports.each = function(fn) {
     var i = 0, len = this.length;
     while (i < len && fn.call(this[i], i, 
     this[i]) !== false) ++i;
     return this;
};
```

The code, which causes the error:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(url, {timeout:0}).catch((err)=> { console.log(err)});

await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on('request', req => {

    if(['image', 'stylesheet', 'font'].indexOf(req.resourceType()) !== -1)
        req.abort();
    else
        req.continue();

    });

 let content = await page.content();
 let $ = cheerio.load(content);



 let gameContent=$('#games_content').children('div').children('div');



 gameContent.children().each(function(i, elem1){

     let league=$(elem1).children('.greenBack').children('.c-events__name').children('a').text().trim();

     $(this).children().each(function(j, elem2){

         if(j!==0) {

             let currentInfo = {};
             currentInfo['league'] = league;

             let shortCut = $(elem2).children('.c-events__item_game').children('.c-events-scoreboard').children();
             let mainInfo = shortCut.first();

             currentInfo['link'] = mainInfo.children("a").attr("href");
             let teams = mainInfo.children("a").children("span").attr("title").trim().split("—");
             currentInfo['team1'] = teams[0].trim();
             currentInfo['team2'] = teams[1].trim();

             let shortCutForTotal = $(elem2).children('.c-events__item_game').children('.c-bets');

         }
     });
 });
```

Thank you in advance!
`

Comment: did you read this part of the error-message: `Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined at Node. (/home/ubuntu/handbot/liveMonitoring.js:211:82)` I don't think this problem has anything to do with `each` it's just part of the stack trace

Comment: Yes, I did. But I did not find something wrong with that part of my code. The most confusing is that sometimes my code works, sometimes the error happens. So I really do not know what to do further

Comment: I have upgraded the post. Thank for the advice

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing these lines of code:

```
page.on('request', req => {

 if(['image', 'stylesheet', 'font'].indexOf(req.resourceType()) !== -1)       
   req.abort();
 else 
   req.continue();

})
```

with the following ones:

```
page.on('request', interceptedRequest => {

     if (interceptedRequest.url().endsWith('.png') || interceptedRequest.url().endsWith('.jpg') || interceptedRequest.url().endsWith('.css'))

         interceptedRequest.abort();
     else

         interceptedRequest.continue();
});
```

and placing `await page.goto(url);` after above lines of code.

Then adding an option `waitUntil:'networkidle0'` to `page.goto(url)`